# How to make a batch file that update Frontend in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, batch-file, module, vba

I have been looking for a simple solution to deploy and replace frontend of MS Access database when Changes are made to frontend copy on the server. I have only found one solution on the internet by [Danny J. Lesandrini](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/msaccess/article.php/3286111/Automatically-Deploy-a-New-Access-Client.htm) that accomplish this but I'm unable to deploy to more than one computer on the network as the file's address is unavoidably hard coded.

The other method I considered base on my reading is to create a batch file that compare the frontend on the client's computer with the one on the server and if different replace the client's frontend with the server's frontend. (this method I would prefer)

The problem is I don't know how to accomplish this and I have not found any sample anywhere to modify to meet my objective. Honestly, I've never created a batch file before but I'm up for learning this with any aid possible. :)

Comment: I looked at the code in the link you provided and that should work just fine. I don't understand the problem where you say the 'file address is hard coded' -- unless you allow the clients to place the database in any folder they choose. In any case, you can modify the code so it will work. You create your OWN Update.mdb file with whatever paths you need. Years ago I created a Version Control package in VB6.0 that would maintain versions of specified programs between HQ (master copy) and remote sites. Then on site, between server ans workstation. You can get this to work.

Comment: But if you really want the batch approach... here is a sample: http://support.adminarsenal.com/entries/22345506-Moving-a-single-file-to-a-workstation

Answer (score 2):

You can easily create a Version Checker in Access.  I have one that looks at the Description property of a form:

```
FileName = Nz(DLookup("Value", "CMDB_tblScreenOptions", "OptionName = 'VersionFilename'"))
CurrentVer = CurrentDb.Containers("Forms").Documents("CMDB_frmScreenAbout").Properties("Description")
```

FileName, in this case, was kept in a table which had it's property set to Hidden.  It stored the path to the text file that I kept the version in.  It would then open that text file:

```
Open FileName For Input As #1
Do While Not EOF(1)
    Input #1, FileVer
Loop
Close #1
```

If CurrentVer = FileVer, everything is fine.  If not, it shells out to a BAT file and then closes the database.  The BAT file has a PAUSE line which gives the user time to allow the DB to close, and then after they "press 'Enter' to continue..." it grabs the current version from the network and installs it on the user's computer.

It sounds a little complicated, but once you figure it out you'll end up using it in every app you create and it becomes easy to incorporate.

Comment: What are the advantages of storing FileVer in a text file instead of in the database?

Comment: @Johnny Its a pleasure having your assistance I've benefited from answers you've posted for others. However, I'm feeling really stupid to say that apart from the first line and partially the second I don't comprehend the application of your answer. I have managed to use the line in my question above but i was stuck at [this](http://imgur.com/gLBqJE5) point.

Comment: HansUp - Not all of our apps use a shared database and I just thought it was easier to develop a system that worked everywhere instead of having to use 2 separate systems.  Kefash - Are you sure checking for an empty string is the proper course?  Did you try checking for NULL?  I don't use the Dir() function so I can't say for sure why it's not working properly.

Comment: I figured out what was wrong. both the new client version stored on the server and the one that was launched from the client was the same. I made the adjustment and it worked like a charm. I'm still very much interested in the method you use. If its not too much trouble can you send me a reference or a sample copy for me to try and incorporate it in what I already have. Thanks again Bones